# How does the Provider Interface used in ViewModel Factory works?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

Recently, I've been reading all over the internet about how to inject ViewModels using Dagger. The most common approach is to create a factory to delegate the creation of the ViewModel. Below is likely the code for the factory:

```
@Singleton
class MainViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return creator.get() as T
    }
}
```

But I can't fully understand the parameter of the factory:

```
private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
```

What exactly is this `Provider` interface? And how does this work?
Also, what is the `@JvmSuppressWildcards` annotation for?

Comment: Well I guess Android devs in SO don't understand the the code either

Comment: the constructor has `@Inject` annotation. Therefore, the map in the constructor is injected by dagger. You define map items in the ViewModelModule class by using `@IntoMap` annotation. Basically, when a viewmodel is injected to any ui component, ViewModelFactory create method is called. In the create method, it simply checks whether map contains provider for that viewmodel. If so, creates it.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a project using Dagger and MVVM and I implement DaggerMultiBinding too.
https://github.com/marjandn/GitHub

***Basically, the scenario is that Dagger will create an implicit Map filled with Provider objects and put it onto the objects graph.***

**With more details:**

We created an annotation class:

```
@MustBeDocumented
@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

basically says that the services returned by these methods should be inserted into Map.
The keys in this Map will be of type Class<? extends ViewModel> and the values will be of type <? extends ViewModel> (subclass of ViewModel).
As a result, Dagger will create an implicit Map filled with Provider objects and put it onto the objects graph

and in ViewModelModules we defined our ViewModels like this:

```
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(DashboardViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindDashboardActivityVM(dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(HomeViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindHomeVM(homeViewModel: HomeViewModel): ViewModel
```

you can see that we use annotation class that we created already for ViewModels.

@IntoMap annotation says that Provider object for this service will be inserted into Map, and @ViewModelKey annotation specifies under which
key it will reside.
The net result of the above code will be that Dagger will create Map data structure
filled with Provider objects and then provide it implicitly to other services.

with this command we get an instance of a viewmodel

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)[getViewModel()]
```

Finally ViewModelFactory class has a Map parameter that is Dagger created Map of ViewModels. and in body of ViewModelFactory searchs in Map to find corresponding Viewmodel.